# Spring Integration / Sleuth / Logback -- What configuration is required so that, via TracingChannelInterceptor, the MDC is updated with given values

Tags: spring-integration, logback, spring-cloud-sleuth, brave

I'm using a framework which includes `spring-cloud-sleuth` (3.1.6) to do tracing but also for setting up the `MappedDiagnosticContext` (MDC) which is then used from `logback` appenders.

I've added `SpringIntegration` (5.5.17) to the mix in order to handle orchestration.  This is working pretty well overall.

I've run into an obstacle with logging, however.  Whereas the logging rules in `logback` are looking for keys within the `MDC`, and this is working from the Servlet filter, those keys are cleared from the `MDC` once the control passes to `SpringIntegration` via a call to a `@MessagingGateway` component.

The `TracingChannelInterceptor` is enabled.  At the point where the `TCI` calls the `beforeHandle()` method, the `MDC` is updated.  Whereas certain keys that were positioned within the `MDC` were positioned from the Servlet context, these keys are removed from the `MDC` by the call to `setSpanInScope()` within `beforeHandle()`.

What is, for me, unfortunate, is that this is a nexus of injected beans at this point, hence many moving parts: `MessageSpanCustomizer`, `BraveSpan`, `BraveTracer`, `MessageHeaderPropagator[GS]etter`, etc ...

Any hints as to the component or components that are managing the `MDC` in this maelstrom of injected behavior?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In my tests I do this:

```
    @Bean
    Tracer simpleTracer(Tracing tracing) {
        return new BraveTracer(tracing.tracer(),
                new BraveCurrentTraceContext(ThreadLocalCurrentTraceContext.create()),
                new BraveBaggageManager());
    }
```

But that is already against Micrometer Tracing, not Spring Cloud Sleuth, so I'm not sure if this can be treat as an answer since I cannot claim that it would work with your project.